# How to bypass a validation rule on event creation?

Tags: validation-rule, event

I want to bypass this validation rule on new event creation and this validation is on contact object

```
NOT(
    OR(
        LEN(Linkeldin__c) = 0,
        REGEX(Linkeldin__c, "^https:\\/\\/[a-z]{2,3}\\.linkedin\\.com\\/in\\/.*$")
    )
)
```

Could someone help please

Comment: Why is the validation on contact running when you create an event?

Comment: hi@fred, On event creation when we add contact to that event, Last Event fields are not populated in the Contact because of validation rule. That's why on event creation we need to bypass the validation rule

Comment: You could only run the validation rule if the last event fields are not populated? Would that work?

Comment: @fred no , it's like we can bypass the validation during the last event field update in contact

Comment: You could check if the last event field had changed and bypass validation if it had?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the front: `!ISNEW() &&`.

The `ISNEW` function returns `true` if the record is being created, so checking `!ISNEW` in your formula will make sure it only errors when the record is being updated.

Documentation is here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions_isnew.htm&type=5